# Linq: where EntityCollection.Contains() not working

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Im having a littel problem with LINQ

I have a EntityCollection of "Resource" Each "Resource" have a EntityCollection of "Applications"

I now need to find the "Rresources" for a particular "Application"

I first find the given application:

```
Application application = (from app in db.ApplicationSet
                           where app.Id == appId
                           select app).First();
```

This gives me the "Application"

I then try to find the applications for this "Application":

```
var res = from rs in db.ResourceSet
          where rs.Applications.Contains(application)
          select rs;
```

This is accepted in VS, but when i run it debug the "result view" returnes with a

"System.SystemException = {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Application_Configuration_Management.Models.Application'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."}"

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LINQ2SQL or EF provider complains that it cannot translate a query that uses an `application` in a context of an `IN` list. Replacing a search for an application followed by a search for one of its resources with a single search for a resource by application ID may work better in your situation:

```
var res = from rs in db.ResourceSet
    where rs.Applications.Any(a => a.Id == appId)
    select rs;
```